# Indexing data from AWS Glue or S3 efficiently into RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jdbc, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I've got some large ETL jobs in AWS Glue using PySpark that output `.parquet` datasets into an S3 bucket.

I'd like to index this data (whether from Glue directly or via some other means using the raw parquet file in S3) into RDS. Normally this isn't too difficult as a one-time import, but this needs to support live indexing:

- syncing changed data very quickly
- being ultra low cost (some of the datasets are 350MM+ rows and I wouldn't want to call a Lambda function 350k times)
- ideally only syncs new or updated rows

I've been considering using change data capture in conjunction with a JDBC connection in a Glue ETL job, but was wondering if there are more performant or faster ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to partition your parquet files around a key representing the age of the data (ex. processing date) and always append records never update or delete past records.

Doing this you can chain the job updating your dataset and a job indexing only the last updates in RDS or ELK.

Doing this you won't process the 350MM+ rows, only the last increment.

An update or a delete will translate into the creation of a new record in your parquet files. To select a particular record you will have to pick the most recent one.